# Best way to use tableView autofill for delegate method in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What is the best way to write delegate and datasource method of tableView in swift.

Like i want to write `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, then should i write complete function? or autofill will work ?

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Because with the case of ObjectiveC I just write `-(NSInteger)number` then using autofill i am able to get whole method.

Comment: Now its not. May be due to beta. future they may support

Comment: Yup, its just suck, we have to type complete method.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Code Snippet** to achieve This.

Step 1

[image: Select Code]

Step 2

[image: Select Name]

Step 3

[image: Use Code]

Step 4

[image]

Comment: How to get My Code Snippet?

Comment: First you need to typeApp code. then Select All code and Long press then Move to right side code Snipet part {}.

Answer (score 1):

Yes autocompletion is not working in Xcode6 Beta release currently available. This is also reported on the Apple dev forum. Take a look: https://devforums.apple.com/message/971642

This may get fixed in the next few beta releases.

Hope that helps!